# How to pass null string in scripts

Tags: shell, sh

How to pass null string using script. as agqmi start 0 "" "" "". if it not able find settings in profile file. And application is not invoking through script. but through command line its working (agqmi start 0 "" "" "").

profile_file

```
APN='airtelgprs.com'

USR='username'

PASS='password'

PAPCHAP='2'



if [ -f "$PROFILE_FILE" ]; then                                       

 echo "Loading profile..." >>$LOG                                

PAPCHAP=`cat agqmi-network.conf | grep 'PAPCHAP' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f2 

-d"'"`                                                                                           
APN=`cat agqmi-network.conf | grep 'APN' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f2 -d"'"`

USR=`cat agqmi-network.conf | grep 'USR' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f2 -d"'"`

PASS=`cat agqmi-network.conf | grep 'PASS' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f2 -d"'"`


if [ "x$PAPCHAP" == "x" ]; then
PAPCHAP="0"
fi

if [ "x$APN" == "x" ]; then
APN="\"\""
fi

if [ "x$USR" == "x" ]; then
USR="\"\"" 
fi

if [ "x$PASS" == "x" ]; then
PASS="\"\""                                                                                     
fi                                                                                                      

fi
```

i tried to execute

```
    STATUS_CMD="./agqmi start "$PAPCHAP" "$APN" "$USR" "$PASS""    
    echo "$STATUS_CMD" >>$LOG                                                      
    `$STATUS_CMD`
```

Comment: you're saying that the character " is part of your input...therefore it is not empty

Comment: then how to pass null string what ever i tried to pass its taking as character. if i tried to pass "" nothing is passing

Comment: but why do you want to do that? you're basically passing 'nothing' to agqmi. Do unset a b c before agqmi start 0 "$a" "$b" "$c"

Comment: my application is not starting if do nothing. but through cmd line it is starting but through script i am not able to start  . In application i am checking strcpy(apn,argv[3]); apn is char array.

Comment: did you do the "unset" thing?

Comment: yes i tried to unset my application is not invoking

Comment: @david Try to do this in one shot: `a= b= c=; agqmi start 0 "$a" "$b" "$c"` and tell us if it doesn't work.

Comment: @konsolebox i tried but not use application not invoking.

Comment: @david On the command-line? But that's just the same as `agqmi start 0 "" "" ""`. Does `agqmi start 0 "" "" ""` work? (on the command-line as well). Please confirm if you run both on command-line.

Comment: @konsolebox, yes its working with cmd line . if i give some string like a="test" b="test" c="test" in script its working, but i leave "" empty its not working using script but in cmd line its working.

Comment: @david Can you update us the whole shell script that doesn't work? Not just the assignments but including the command to run `agqmi` as well. You can edit your post. Place it one code block.

Comment: @konsolebox i have added, if want more information please tell me

Comment: Piping cat to grep is silly.  Piping cat to grep to awk is humorous.  Piping cat to grep to awk to cut is absurd!  A little awk goes a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to run your command in a way that you store it first is through this (use arrays):

```
STATUS_CMD=(./agqmi start "$PAPCHAP" "$APN" "$USR" "$PASS")
echo "${STATUS_CMD[*]}" >>$LOG
"${STATUS_CMD[@]}"
```

You could also use `eval` but it could misinterpret it depending on the values of your variables.

And you probably no longer need to re-assign your variables that's meant to be empty to `""` (literal). Only the one that needs to be converted to `0`:

```
if [ "x$PAPCHAP" == "x" ]; then
    PAPCHAP="0"
fi
#if [ "x$APN" == "x" ]; then
#    APN="\"\""
#fi
#if [ "x$USR" == "x" ]; then
#    USR="\"\""
#fi
#if [ "x$PASS" == "x" ]; then
#    PASS="\"\""
#fi
```

And your comparisons need no markers like `x`. Using `[[ ]]` is also recommended.

```
if [[ $PAPCHAP == '' ]]; then  ## Or simply [[ -z $PAPCHAP ]]
    PAPCHAP=0
fi
```

Update for POSIX:

```
if [ -z "$PAPCHAP" ]; then
    PAPCHAP=0
fi
#if [ -z "$APN" ]; then
#    APN=''
#fi
#if [ -z "$USR" ]; then
#    USR=''
#fi
#if [ -z "$PASS" ]; then
#    PASS=''
#fi

STATUS_CMD="./agqmi start \"$PAPCHAP\" \"$APN\" \"$USR\" \"$PASS\""
echo "$STATUS_CMD" >>"$LOG"
./agqmi start "$PAPCHAP" "$APN" "$USR" "$PASS"  ## Just execute it directly and not inside a variable.
```

And maybe you should not add `./`?

```
STATUS_CMD="agqmi start \"$PAPCHAP\" \"$APN\" \"$USR\" \"$PASS\""
echo "$STATUS_CMD" >>"$LOG"
agqmi start "$PAPCHAP" "$APN" "$USR" "$PASS"
```

You actually don't need to store it on a variable anyway:

```
echo "agqmi start \"$PAPCHAP\" \"$APN\" \"$USR\" \"$PASS\"" >>"$LOG"
agqmi start "$PAPCHAP" "$APN" "$USR" "$PASS"
```

Comment: ./agqmi-network: line 103: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "}")

Comment: I dont know much about scripting your answer may right but i am facing syntax error

Comment: @david Are you sure you're running it with bash? (`bash script.sh`)

Comment: Do you have bash? Can you save it with `#!/bin/bash` instead?

Comment: i am using embedded device in that kernel, bash doesnt exits

Comment: I see. You shouldn't have tagged this thread with `bash` as we assume that you're targetting it when you do. If you want to save your command on a single string, you can only use eval which is dangerous. I'll post some suggestions.

Comment: you saved my day really thanks alot. I should not store a variable.   ./agqmi start "$PAPCHAP" "$APN" "$USR" "$PASS"  this is enough thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing "\0" as parameter?

I have a solaris server and whenever I need to pass NULL string as parameter I use "\0".

Your command would look like

`agqmi start 0 "\0" "\0" "\0"`

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: no if i use like that it is taking as character of ". because i am executing agqmi start 0 "\0" "\0" "\0" by storing in variable. idle case i need not to pass any variable for null string to pass. leaving with a= will work.

Comment: It might work for you. But if you do not pass anything all parameters becomes null. In my case some times I need to pass a param as null but next param as not null. So I pass parameters like `command param1 param2 param3` param1 goes in $1, param2 in $2 and so on. You might need to use a parameter as null which is not a last parameter. in that case I use `command param1 "\0" param2 param3`
In this case param1 goes in $1, param2 in $3 and param3 in $4. This solves my purpose.